# Why can Python use underline instead of dot on import

Tags: python, import

For example we can use `oslo_db` to replace `oslo.db` to import (see the first comment on [this patch set](https://review.openstack.org/#/c/124004/8/neutron/db/allowedaddresspairs_db.py):

> ```
> from oslo.db import exception as db_exc
> ```
>
> YAMAMOTO Takashi: oslo_db

And I can't find the `oslo_db` module in the OpenStack git repo or search for it in pip.

What's more, I boot a VM and find that it's ok to use `oslo_db` or `oslo.db` since I only installed `oslo.db`.

image: (`import oslo_db` example and I only installed `oslo.db`):

[image]

I have seen a article about this, but sorry that I have forget it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can't** just use `_` to replace the `.` separator. Not without additional effort by the module authors.

For any module that you can, there is an *actual extra module* with the name with an underscore importing the packaged namespace.

See the [`oslo` GitHub package](http://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/oslo.db/tree/) for example, where you'll find two top-level directories, each with a `__init__.py` file to make them packages: `oslo` and `oslo_db`.

This is almost invariably done to transition from one style to the other, and allowing both versions makes the transition easier. In this case it appears the developers are moving *away* from the `oslo.db` nested namespace; the [changelog for 1.4.0](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/oslo.db/history.html#id7) includes the entry:

> - Move files out of the namespace package

and the [commit message states](http://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/oslo.db/commit/?id=7063585c60205fe031e1c74289d88886705cfb57):

> Move the public API out of oslo.db to oslo_db. Retain the ability to
>   import from the old namespace package for backwards compatibility for
>   this release cycle.

The linked Launchpad Blueprint is no longer available so you'll have to ask the OpenStack community as to why they did this.

Python project names do not have to correspond with the packages and modules that they contain. For example, the BeautifulSoup project packages their `bs4` module as `beautifulsoup4`. As such the `oslo_db` package is part of the `oslo.db` Python project.

Comment: @Wei: you'll have to ask that project as to why they provide both names. Presumably they are transitioning from one style to the other.

Comment: Thx! And because oslo.db and oslo_db are both add in setup.cfg, we can import both? right?
https://github.com/openstack/oslo.db/blob/master/setup.cfg

Comment: @Wei: yes, they are both available. The intention is clearly to move away from `oslo.db` however.

Comment: I've made a experiment:
http://postimg.org/image/t1tws3br1/
And I think I have find out it, thank you!